# Axios get request returns undefined for the first time in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, request

I am using DRF for creating the api.. I am able to fetch the data using axios, but it returns undefined the first time and hence, when I use `useState`, it gets set as undefined..

ItemDetail.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
const ItemDetail = () => {


    const [detail, setDetail] = useState('')

    const [id, setId] = useState('')



    const RecipeDetail = async () => {

        const res = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/recipe-detail/1`,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            }

        })

        setDetail(res.data)

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        RecipeDetail()

    }, [id])

    console.log(`Hi ${detail}`)


    return (
        <div>
            Hi
        </div>

    )
}

export default ItemDetail
```

So why is the API returning undefined for the first time?
I read few answers regarding the use of async/await which I have.. Also, when I `console.log(detail)`, it logs it multiple times.. Why is that so?
[image]
As u can see in the image, it logs multiple times..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const ItemDetail = () => {
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState('');

  const RecipeDetail = async () => {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/recipe-detail/1',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },

    });

    setDetail(res.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    RecipeDetail();
  }, [detail]);

  console.log(`Hi ${detail}`);

  return (
    <div>
      {detail ? 'Hi' : 'Loading ... '}
    </div>

  );
};

export default ItemDetail;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access or log the detail before it is set ,means that useEffect will be called after your content is rendered so console.log(`Hi ${detail}`); ran first and undefined was logged , later useEffect ran and RecipeDetail(); data received state changed as you called setState. and rerender occured again and this time you received value.

Comment: Please upvote the question if u found it useful

Answer (score 0):

When it was first rendered, no API response was received yet.
and then, when second rendered, API resonse was receiced.

Comment: I understand that.. How can I correct it? I don't want undefined as a value being stored in my `state`.. Also, if u can answer the whole question